# Android 8 notification not showing up, ActivityThread throws RemoteServiceException

Tags: android, notifications

In the Developer console it shows me, that this error only exists on Android 8 and it is showy often on Xperia Devices... This doesn't match to the distribution of the app over devices / Android versions.....
At this time, I have no idea how to handle this problem. Maybee it is related to some special cases or combinations of devices and Android 8. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdQtr.png)
And this is my Main Code to show the notification PS ( ALREADY TRY SVG/PNG/ ALL SIZES) same problem

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    api = AFClientService.newBuilder(this)
            .setCarrierId("*****")
            .setHostUrl("********************")
            .setVPNNotificationProvider(new VPNNotificationProvider() {
                // NOTE: this method will be called from VPN process, reference to MainApplication will be different
                @Override
                public Notification createVPNNotification(String message, String ticker, boolean b, long l, VpnStatus.ConnectionStatus connectionStatus) {
                    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "*****")
                            .setContentText(message)
                            .setTicker(ticker)
                            .setContentTitle("**********")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                            .build();
                }
            })
            .build();
}
public AFClientService getApi() {
    return api;
}
```

Comment: are you using any library for showing the vpn notification ?

Comment: -- import android.app.Notification;
-- import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
-- import com.northghost.caketube.AFClientService;
-- import com.northghost.caketube.VPNNotificationProvider;